# Printf with multiple threads (for real-time logging) in C

Tags: c, multithreading, logging, pthreads

I have written a code for real-time logging. Here's the pseudo-code:

```
initialize Q; //buffer structure stores values to be printed

log(input)
{
   push input to Q;
}

printLog() //infinte loop
{
    loop(1)
    {
         if(Q is not empty) 
         {
               values = pop(Q);
               msg = string(values); //formating values into a message string
               print(msg);
         } 
    }

}

mainFunction()
{
    loop(1)
    {
       /* 
         insert operations to be performed
       */
       log(values); //log function called
    }
}

main()
{
   Create 4 threads; //1 mainFunction and 3 printLog
   Bind them to CPUs;
}
```

I'm using atomic operations instead of locks.

When I print the output to the console, I see that each thread prints consecutively for a while. This must mean that once a thread enters printLog(), the other threads are inactive for a while.
What I want instead is while one thread is printing, another thread formats the next value popped from Q and prints it right after. How can this be achieved?

EDIT: I've realized the above information isn't sufficient. Here are some other details.

1. Buffer structure Q is a circular array of fixed size.
2. Pushing information to Q is faster than popping+printing. So by the time the Buffer structure is full, I want most of the information to be printed.
   NOTE: mainFunction thread shouldn't wait to fill Buffer when it is full.

I'm trying to utilize all the threads at a given time. Currently, after one thread prints, the same thread reads and prints the next value (this means the other 2 threads are inactive).

Here's the actual code:

```
//use gcc main.c -o run -pthread 
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3

/* Buffer size */
#define BUFFER_SIZE  1000

struct values
{
    uint64_t num;
    char msg[20];
};
struct values Q[BUFFER_SIZE];

int readID    = -1;
int writeID   = -1;
int currCount =  0;

void Log(uint64_t n, char* m)
{
    int i;
    if (__sync_fetch_and_add(&currCount,1) < BUFFER_SIZE)
    {               
        i = __sync_fetch_and_add(&writeID,1); 
        i = i%BUFFER_SIZE;

        Q[i].num = n;
        strcpy(Q[i].msg, m);
    }
    else __sync_fetch_and_add(&currCount,-1);               
}

void *printLog(void *x)
{
    int thID = *((int*)(x));
    int i;
    while(1)
    {   
        if(__sync_fetch_and_add(&currCount,-1)>=0)
        { 
            i = __sync_fetch_and_add(&readID,1);                                               
            i = i%BUFFER_SIZE;

            printf("ThreadID: %2d, count: %10d, message: %15s\n",thID,Q[i].num,Q[i].msg);            
        }
        else __sync_fetch_and_add(&currCount,1);
    }
}

void *mainFunction()
{
    uint64_t i = 0;
    while(1)
    {       
        Log(i,"Custom Message");
        i++;
        usleep(50);
    }
}

int main()
{
        /* Set main() Thread CPU */
        cpu_set_t cpusetMain;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpusetMain);
        CPU_SET(0, &cpusetMain);
        if(0 != pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpusetMain))
        printf("pthread_setaffinity_np failed for CPU: 0\n");
        

        int LogThID[N+1];
        pthread_t LogThreads[N+1];
        /* Create Threads */
        if (pthread_create(&LogThreads[0], NULL, &mainFunction, NULL) != 0){return 0;}
        for(int i=1; i<N+1 ; i++)
        {
            LogThID[i] = i;
            if (pthread_create(&LogThreads[i], NULL, &printLog, &LogThID[i]) != 0){return i;}
        }

        /* Set CPUs */
        cpu_set_t cpuset[N+1];
        for(int i=0; i<N+1; i++)
        {
            CPU_ZERO(&cpuset[i]);
            CPU_SET(i+1, &cpuset[i]);
            if(0 != pthread_setaffinity_np(LogThreads[i], sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset[i])) 
                        printf("pthread_setaffinity_np failed for CPU: %d\n", i+1);      
        }
        struct sched_param param[N+1];
        for(int i=0; i<N+1; i++)
        {
            param[i].sched_priority = 91;
            if(0 != pthread_setschedparam(LogThreads[i],SCHED_FIFO,&param[i]))
            printf("pthread_setschedparam failed for CPU: %d\n", i);
        }

        /* Join threads */
        for(int i=0; i<N+1; i++) 
        {
            pthread_join(LogThreads[i], NULL);
        }
          
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't run pseudocode on my machine, please post a [mcve].

Comment: One printing thread is enough. Also, make sure that you will not call print again before another call  finishes.

Comment: Why should *this be achieved?* What are you trying to do? One supplier one consumer for the queue would be sufficient.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have added the original code now

Comment: @Gerhard Writing to the buffer memory is a lot faster than reading+printing and the buffer memory is limited.

Comment: @Vignatha Vinjam Three printing threads will not decrease the amount of buffering memory required.